# How to use Ning API in iphone development

Tags: iphone, ios, ning

I have Ning Network and I have already developed an iOS app for the network.
I would like to use the Ning API for make possible for user upload pictures from the app to the network.
I known that i have to use the Ning API, but I have no idea how to use it in X-Code.
If someone could help me I would appreciate.

thanks in advance!

Guilherme

Answer (score 0):

Though your question is too broad to answer I would summarize as,

If you are new to iOS development you have to learn iOS programming and following are the options I see currently,

1. See these  [tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials), where in depth knowledge is given and also step by step, so easy to learn.
2. You can also download [ebook](http://www.apress.com/9781430236054) if you are fan of digital book reading.
3. You can search around net and will find lots of tutorials how to learn iOS programming.